# How to fix ' Alrady print all array element of last row elements'

Tags: c

Always come last row answer of the array...

initialize the variables...

```
int row,column;
row=0;
column=0;
int i,j;
i=0,j=0;
int my_array[row][column];
int sum=0;
```

User can enter the array values...

```
printf("enter row values & column value:\n ");
printf("row value i :");
scanf("%d",&i);
printf("column value :");
scanf("%d",&j);
printf("Set the values...\n");
printf("\n");
```

Get array to values...

```
for(row=0;row<=i-1;row++)
{
    for(column=0;column<=j-1;column++)
    {
        printf("Enter value for my_array[%d][%d] :",row,column);
                    scanf("%d",&my_array[row][column]);

     }
}
```

Print the array....

```
for(row=0;row<=i-1;row++)
{
    for(column=0;column<=j-1;column++)
    {
        printf("%d ",my_array[row][column]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

 //end of the code
 return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem,

```
int row,column;
row=0;
column=0;
// ...
int my_array[row][column];
```

You create a zero by zero array. It doesn't matter that you later assign values to `row` and `column` via `scanf`because by then you've already created `my_array`. There are two solutions:

**1. Create the array with a predetermined size.**

This alone fixes your code alone as the user never inputs values that overrun your buffer. (if you are new to C and want to understand what I mean, try experimenting with setting `row` and `column` to 25 to start with. Your program will work. But then see what happens when you try to go *over* a 25 by 25 array. Oh no, the code breaks again!).

**2. Dynamically allocate memory using `malloc`.**

Declare a 2d array like so:

```
int **my_array;
```

Once you've got `row`, you `malloc(sizeof(int *) * row);`, then you loop through `my_array`, allocating columns. If that all sounds completely alien to you I recommend checking out [Beej's Guide to C Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgc/html/single/bgc.html#pointers)'s section on pointers. Good luck!